# Applying both replace and filter to an object

Tags: javascript

I need to filter an object by only taking in results that have ".com" in the string whilst also removing a string from it. I can remove the string and the results go into my DB perfectly however I am struggling with the filter. Is there a way I can call both the replace and filter functions inside the same variable being companyFilter?

Assume the object is:

```
[{
company: 'amazon'
companyurl:'amazon.com'
}
{
company: '400 prize money'
companyurl:'400 prize money'
}
{
company: 'facebook'
companyurl:'facebook.com'
}
{
company: 'google'
companyurl:'google.com'
}
]

    const newObject = data.map((item) => {
    const companyNoCom = item['companyurl'].replace(/hackerone.com\//g, "")
    //const companyFilter = data.filter((item) => item['company'].includes('.com'))
    newItem = {...item, 
      company: companyNoCom,
    }
    
    return newItem
    })

    console.log(newObject)
```

The required output would be:

```
 [{
 company: 'amazon'
 companyurl:'amazon.com'
  }
 {
 company: 'facebook'
 companyurl:'facebook.com'
 }
company: 'google'
companyurl:'google.com'
}
]
```

Comment: Filter, then map i.e. `const newObject = data.filter((item) => item['company'].includes('.com')).map(...)`

Comment: What is the required output?

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map()` ALWAYS returns ALL results but allows changes to each object within the array.

`Array.filter()` on the other hand ONLY filters and cannot change individual objects within the array and should only return a boolean.

If you need to first make changes to the data in order to determine if it should be included, run `.map` first, then `.filter` on the results of `map()`. The original data will be unchanged and `newObject` will contain your results:

```
var newObject = data
    .map((item) => {
        item['companyurl'] = item['companyurl'].replace(/hackerone.com\//g, "");
        return item;
    })
    .filter((item) => item['companyurl'].includes('.com'));

    // Note. the original data array will not be changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    company: 'amazon',
    companyurl:'amazon.com'
  },
  {
    company: '400 prize money',
    companyurl:'400 prize money'
  }, 
  {
    company: 'facebook',
    companyurl:'facebook.com'
  }, 
  {
    company: 'google',
    companyurl:'google.com'
  }
]

const result = data.filter(item => item.companyurl.includes(".com")).map(item => ({...item, company: item.companyurl.split(".com")[0]}))
                    
console.log(result)
```

EDIT: I made an adjustment to match desired output, so with this one you would always get company value coming from companyurl after striping .com part

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { company: "amazon", companyurl: "amazon.com" },
  { company: "400 prize money", companyurl: "400 prize money" },
  { company: "facebook", companyurl: "facebook.com" },
  { company: "google", companyurl: "google.com" },
];
const newObject = data.filter((item) => item.companyurl.includes(".com"));
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String.prototype.endsWith()` to check if the end of the string is `.com` and filter by this:

```js
const arr = [{
  company: 'amazon',
  companyurl:'amazon.com'
  },
  {
  company: '400 prize money',
  companyurl:'400 prize money'
  },
  {
  company: 'facebook',
  companyurl:'facebook.com'
  },
  {
  company: 'google',
  companyurl:'google.com'
  }
];


const res = arr.filter(({ companyurl }) => companyurl.endsWith('.com'));

console.log(res);
```